# How to make normal http service calls between two micro services asynchronous in Lagom

Tags: lagom

I was going through Lagom documentation and want to clarify one thing with respect to microservice to microservice communication. We have the below use case.

WebBrowser <--http--> MicroService1 <--http--> MicroService2.

This is purely synchronous communication using http.

Is it possible to make this communication asynchronous using Lagom?

I am unable to get a concrete example in your documentation. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is, Microservice1 needs to bind Microservice2.
  From there it can call and get an async response.

As far as the communication from the browser, the idea is the same except that there is no binding. It would just call a REST endpoint.

http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/java/ServiceClients.html

Hope this helps.